# Kotlin Generic Inheritence how to cast to inherited object

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following case.

Base class for my object.

```
abstract class A{
  lateinit var x: Animal
  fun defineStuff() {
    x = Factory().createFor(getAnimalType())
  }
  abstract fun <T: Animal> getAnimalType(): Class<T>
}
```

I have both Animal and Dog defined so:

```
open class Animal
class Dog : Animal()
```

the Factory class is provided for me by my framework. this is the signature:

```
fun <T: Animal> createFor(animalType: Class<T>): T
```

and now I made the following class:

```
class B : A() {

  override fun <T: Animal> getAnimalType(): Class<T> {
      return Dog::class.java as Class<T>
  }
}
```

the following line is highlighted by my linter as "Unchecked Class"

does that mean I am doing something wrong? is there a better way to use generics in Kotlin that will not produce a warning? or should I just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a better solution in my opinion `A` should be generic (as `A` is abstract and one of quite important thing is the type of boxed value). Then, you could do following:

```
abstract class A<T: Animal> {
    lateinit var x: T
    fun defineStuff() {
        x = Factory().createFor(getAnimalType())
    }
    abstract fun getAnimalType(): Class<T>
}

class DogA: A<Dog>() {
    override fun getAnimalType() = Dog::class.java
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type is indeed erased at runtime. That’s what the warning is about.

A caller of your code can do this:

```
val b: B = B()
val catClass: Class<Cat> = b.getAnimalType()
```

The compiler will allow this. The code will run without throwing an exception.

Your base function should not be generic, it should instead have a return type of `Class<out Animal>`.